# TDengine database join stable "invalid column name"

Tags: tdengine

The SQL command is:
`select int_col from super, superb where super.ts = superb.ts and super.int_tag = sup erb.int_tag;`
and the result shows `DB error: invalid operation: invalid column name`.
However, I check the column name of my stable, there is no problem:
[image]
Can anyone tell what's wrong here? I don't think I have a syntax error in my SQL command

Answer (score 0):

`int_col` in `select int_col from super, superb where super.ts = superb.ts and super.int_tag = sup erb.int_tag;` is meaningless because both of your super table have a column called `int_col`.
You should change your SQL command to：
`select super.int_col from super, superb where super.ts = superb.ts and super.int_tag = sup erb.int_tag;`
or
`select superb.int_col from super, superb where super.ts = superb.ts and super.int_tag = sup erb.int_tag;`